# Configure Octave to avoid automatic endfor, endif auto-completion

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm using Octave to teach my students. The course is about MATLAB and Octave, and we need all the code was compatible between MATLAB and Octave. The version of Octave installed on university computers automatically sets an endif or endfor when a program is being typed, and we need all the code blocks to simply use end.
Is there a way to configure Octave to not automatically do this endif or endfor autocomplete?

Answer (score 2):

In Octave v4.4.1 on MacOS, there is an option in Preferences->Editor (you'll have to scroll down to see it):

[image]

Comment: I'm using GNU Octave, version 4.2.2 under Ubuntu, and this option doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by the maintainers [in the submitted bug report](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?59460), this option does actually exist.

Go to the preferences dialogue, on the editor tab. Now ***scroll*** down, to the "Indentation" section. There should be an option there saying 'Auto insert after "if" etc.' and a drop down dialogue there giving you the options "Nothing", "endif etc", and "end".

Comment: if you _do_ create such a ticket on the octave bug tracker, please comment here with a link to the bug. (Alternatively, I'm happy to do this for you if you prefer, and don't particularly care about being notified about the bug's progress).

Comment: I think the bug track is a good idea, but I'm not used to doing it, so I would be delighted and very grateful if you did it, @Tasos Papastylianou

Comment: @SantiagoHigueradeFrutos submitted to the octave bug tracker as [bug #59460](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?59460)

Comment: Bug report indicated the following should work:  Go to the "Editor" tab of the preferences and select your preferred behavior from the drop-down list labeled "Auto insert after "if" etc.".   if you can confirm the option is missing that should be noted on the bug report

Comment: @SantiagoHigueradeFrutos tagging you here to make sure you saw Nick's message. There is a scrollbar in the editor preferences, which I admit I also missed! There's a dropdown menu under 'indentation', which does exactly what you need!

Comment: @NickJ thanks Nick! This does indeed do exactly what OP had wanted. I do wonder if perhaps the fact both Santiago and I totally missed the fact there is a scrollbar on that page may be a useful point to consider on the UX side of things though ... I made a comment on the bugtracker to that effect :)

Comment: Thanks. I have seen the drop down list in some computers in my university yesterday. Not in my 4.2.2 version under Ubuntu. But, in Ubuntu, Octave doesn't write the endif, it writes simply end. I think a post in the student's blog explaining how to configure their computers will solve the problem.